# Sass importing bower components

Tags: import, sass, bower, susy

I have moved over from COMPASS to Libsass, the speeds are great but I need to use a few bower components to get this working.

It may be a bit pedantic but I have to import my components like this at the top of my scss file.

```
   @import "../bower_components/compass-mixins/lib/compass";
   @import "../bower_components/susy/sass/susy";
```

It's ugly, is there a way to either import them via grunt or alias the files so I could do

```
 @import "compass";
 @import "susy";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To manage your dependencies, you can use **Grunt Wiredep** (https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep) to automatically add the files in your **main.scss** file.

Add the main.scss to your wiredep config.

```
wiredep: {

  task: {    

    src: [
      'app/styles/main.scss',  // .scss & .sass support...
    ]
  }
}
```

And pop this in your **main.scss** file.

```
// bower:scss
// endbower
```

Hope that helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I just used the grunt with Gruntfile.js in this case, by adding loadPath, with the location of bower_components folder, it is in the same level as a project in my case:

```
    sass: {
        dev: {
            options: {
                style: 'expanded',
                compass: false,
                loadPath: 'bower_components'
            },
            files: {
                '<%= project.css %>/style.css': '<%= project.scss %>/style.scss'
            }
        }
    },
```

After just change your @import section to:

```
@import "compass-mixins/lib/compass";
@import "susy/sass/susy";
```